# Hip pain when doing a back squat or front squat

Tags: squats, pain, quads

I have hip pain in the side of my leg when I back or front squat. It generally feels just very tight or small pain when I first start a workout cycle, and after a couple weeks the pain gets bad enough to where I have to lower the weight significantly and go slow, or stop, as it becomes more painful. It only starts hurting once I get to the parellel position or lower. It reduces pain if I drop down more quickly rather than slowly lower my body. It's almost as if the tendon or whatever is taking on the weight more than my quad muscles are, damaging it. I cant pinpoint the muscle, I would guess tensor fascia latae but based on pictures it seems kind of high.. I posted a diagram with a circle on it below where I am having pain. My question is what causes this(tight quads maybe)?, how do I fix it? I'd like to keep growing my leg muscles while working it out. I seem to be able to do some other leg exercises better such as bulgarian split squat or landmine squat, although the tendon hurts if Ive backsquatted earlier in the week when doing these exercises. When I do my squat form, i bend my knees, externally rotate my knees a bit, and try to sit back and down. I have better luck using lighter weight(like 50% of 1rm).

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you might have torn some muscle tissue, or at least inflamed it. You could visit your doctor to see if he detects any actual damage. Whether your doctor detects anything or not, he is going to recommend that you lay off of exercising that muscle for about 6-months for it to heal.

Comment: after it heals it seems to repetitively occur, same leg.. do you know what could be causing that? or just maybe too much weight and didnt warm up enough i guess

Comment: In my case, it's too much weight and didn't warm up enough for years (I am 51). After it heals, you could always try going lightweight with hi reps. I started doing 20 to 30 reps each set a few years ago, and it makes your leg muscles burn like wildfire.

Comment: [Lateral hip pain?](https://squatuniversity.com/2018/02/04/fixing-lateral-hip-pain/)

Comment: This...is borderline for diagnose me, which is off topic. Can you generalize it a bit? Also, gross motor tendons generally have very few pain receptors. It's more likely you're getting referred pain from the muscle that makes you feel it's tendon.

Comment: john p thanks for using the "..." for dramatic effect. I'm not looking for a diagnosis, I am looking how to correct hip pain during the squat, and how to prevent it in the future